# Create clean DNS configurations

Tags: dns

I'm concerned about creating a clean / easy managed DNS configuration for a domain.

Every time I have to manage a new domain, previous configurations are just dozens and dozens of A records pointing to IPs. I always use CNAMES as follow:

> server1.mydomain.com       A         X.XX.XX.XX
>   main.mydomain.com          CNAME   server1.mydomain.com
>   *.mydomain.com                  CNAME   main.mydomain.com
>   ...                                    CNAME   main.mydomain.com

This way if I need to switch servers I just change "main" and that's it.

However, I'm concerned about having too many CNAME jumps. Can it have an impact on performance, security, whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `CNAME` level means another request to your DNS server, if I went to `test.mydomain.com` I'd get a reply saying it was a `CNAME` for `main.mydomain.com`, then I'd request `main.mydomain.com` which is a `CNAME` for `server1.mydomain.com` then I'd make a request for `server1.mydomain.com`  which will reply with IP X.XX.XX.XX . So, three requests for 1 IP address.

This means larger replies, and more work for your DNS server. On a small scale this isn't much of an issue, but if you get 100's of thousands of requests for your domain, sending larger replies is not efficient, either in terms of bandwidth or workload on your server, but it is neither illegal, insecure or wrong. If you find it's the best way to manage your domains, weigh the efficiency costs against the increased administrative work you'd have to do and make your choice.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer, I believe I won't add more than one CNAME level then!